# Enum throwing a Constructor error

Tags: java, enums

I have created a class to hold currency types. 
Class is called Currency. Its contents are -

```
public class Currency{
            public enum CurrencyType {PENNY(1), NICKLE(5), DIME(10), QUARTER(25)};
}
```

In Eclipse, PENNY, NICKLE etc are highlighted in red and error message reads -

```
The constructor Currency.CurrencyType(int) is undefined
```

Why this error?

Comment: You have not defined the private constructor accepting an int for `CurrencyType`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there's no constructor `CurrencyType(int)`. You'll need to create an explicit constructor if you don't list the enums as just `PENNY, NICKLE, etc.`.

Add a constructor to your enum as follows:

```
public enum CurrencyType {
    PENNY(1), NICKEL(5), DIME(10), QUARTER(25);
    int value;
    CurrencyType(int value) {
       this.value = value;
    }
    int getValue() {
       return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you have no constructor in your enum for the parameter (int)

you can make a constructor in your enum

```
CurrencyType (int value){//Whatever you want to do with it }
```

And for the future: the error message says clearly whats wrong. most of the times you can save yourself so much work, if you just read the errorMessage. (and maybe do a little google research)